# How do i set this ACL on the router

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-commands, acl, interface

I was told in a previous answer to use

```
ip access-list extended TEST
 deny ip host <PC0 address> host <PC5 address>
 permit ip any any
```

But, whats the command to set it on the router interface?

Like you would usually use `ip access-group 101 out`.

Comment: previous question can be found http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34267/simple-acl-question/34268#34268

Comment: Has either answer satisfied your questions? If your question has been answered, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you seem to have the answer in your question:

```
ip access-group 101 out
```

Although, with extended access lists like 101, you should put them as close to the source as possible, so you normally would put that on the inbound interface, rather than the outbound interface:

```
ip access-group 101 in
```

The same would hold true for a named ACL:

```
ip access-group TEST in
```

Put a standard ACL on the outbound interface as close to the destination as possible (the interface to the destination), and an extended ACL as close to the source as possible (the interface from the source). This will keep a standard ACL from blocking too much traffic, and an extended ACL has both a source and destination, so it will keep the routers from routing traffic that will be dropped anyway.